# network spec is different between lshw and /sys/class/net/eth0/speed

Tags: networking, ethernet, pcie

I just wanted to know my server spec.

so I tried `lshw -c network` and `cat /sys/class/net/eth0/speed`

But `lshw` shows capacity 1Gbit/s and `cat /sys/class/net/eth0/speed` shows 10000.

What is more correct?

My ethernet card is 'NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe'

Comment: And what does `sudo ethtool eth0` report?

Comment: @muru `ethtool` shows 10000, it stands to reason that `ethtool` read /sys/class/net/eth0/speed